# What's the effect of passing a scalar in turtle.color() in Skulpt?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, skulpt

When I try running my python code below, how does [turtle.color](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.color) interpret the input as a number?

```
import turtle

for i in ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 8, 10]:
       turtle.color(i)
       turtle.forward(100)
       turtle.right(90)
```

Actual:

Output I am getting is a square with sides in the given order.
When it reaches `turtle.color(8)`, one of the sides is overwritten with black,
followed by next side (`turtle.color(10)`).

Expected:

The code should error out as `turtle.color(8)`, doesn't make sense!!

I am actually using an online turtle compiler to test my code ([repl.it/languages/python_turtle](https://repl.it/languages/python_turtle)).

Comment: Have you tried going over `turtle.color` source code and see what it does?

Comment: It gives an error for me. Are you sure this is the exact code you are running?

Comment: yes, this is the exact code i am running.

Comment: Your code raises a `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` exception when I run it.

Comment: The website you used doesn't run the code with a normal python interpreter. So this question is not related to python, but only related to the specific website. Therefore I vote to close this post as it is not reproducible by others.

Comment: Or change the question to reflect the specific website.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel for the clarification..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [blog](https://repl.it/site/blog/python-turtle), repl.it mentions they use [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) as their webIDE.

Skulpt's [Github](https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/351e6dab331881ec79d166e751cb6894dcd75574/src/lib/turtle.js) page shows the following function which suggests that 'Black' is the default. This explains the odd behavior you are seeing vs others while debugging.

```
function createColor(color, g, b, a) {
    var i;

    if (g !== undefined) {
        color = [color, g, b, a];
    }

    if (color.constructor === Array && color.length) {
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            color[i] = (typeof color[i] === "number") ?
                Math.max(0, Math.min(255, parseInt(color[i]))) :
                0;
        }
        if (typeof color[i] === "number") {
            color[3] = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, color[i]));
            color = "rgba(" + color.join(",") + ")";
        }
        else {
            color = "rgb(" + color.slice(0,3).join(",") + ")";
        }
    }
    else if (typeof color === "string" && !color.match(/\s*url\s*\(/i)) {
        color = color.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    }
    else {
        return "black";
    }

    return color;
}
```

Comment: turtle.color("10") / turtle.color("Hello") - gives an output Black

Comment: Thanks for testing Richin. It looks like this is your answer. The 8 and 10 are being passed in as strings and therefore printing __black__.

Comment: thanks Daniel..however, i just tried running the below code without a for loop and it gives me black again                                                                                    
import turtle
turtle.color(10)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)

Comment: Are you running the most current version of Turtle? (Its strange that turtle.color(10) doesn't error out on you like for others in comments section.)

Comment: i am actually using an online turtle compiler to test my code (https://repl.it/languages/python_turtle)

Comment: I'm betting that repl.it uses some behind the scenes magic to reduce errors for learning purposes. I would suggest trying outside of repl.it, as results are probably going to differ. (I just verified on repl.it that turtle.color(10) does in fact print black.)

Comment: Edited answer to reflect my last comment.